# How to use reflection for accessing object from its name as a string

Tags: vb.net, reflection

Ive a folder monitoring application where around 25 filewatchers monitoring 25 folders. Each of the filewatchers named fsw1,fsw2 ....

```
bCreateFileCheck = True
fsw1 = New FileSystemWatcher(My.Settings.UserRootFolder1)
fsw1.IncludeSubdirectories = True
fsw1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
fsw1.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName)
```

So this is repeating for the 25 folders, but only difference is name changing of fsw1 to fsw2,fsw3 etc. and also My.Settings.UserRootFolder1 to My.Settings.UserRootFolder2,My.Settings.UserRootFolder3 etc.

So how can we achieve this using for loop without writing individual code blocks for every filewatchers. I guess using some reflection techniques it can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make your life harder than it needed to be. Use an array (or `List(Of T)` if you need something flexible):

```
Dim watchers(24) As FileSystemWatcher
For i As Integer = 0 To watchers.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim path = CStr(My.Settings.Item("UserRootFolder" & (i + 1)))
    watchers(i) = New FileSystemWatcher(path)
    'Do further initialization...       
Next
```

If the structure is fixed and you cannot really change it, you can set the variables to the objects that you created in the `For` loop. So change the loop as follows:

```
'...
Dim watcher = New FileSystemWatcher(...)
Me.GetType().GetField("fsw" & (i + 1)).SetValue(Me, watcher)
```

This gets the field with the appropriate name and sets its value to the object that you just created (I assume that it is a field based on its naming).

Comment: Sorry friend, actually its an existing code on the project been runnning for 3  4 years i guess. So there is lots of places where its using. So any possibility with that way other than array?

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend refactoring the code. If that is not an option, I have added some more information to my answer.

Comment: Thats really nice my friend.. Thanks for that.. Made my day